# How to have a ball go through a hoop in spritekit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a basketball rim png that I want a basketball to go through if the user taps on the correct location above the rim but whenever I tap the screen for the ball to drop down, it always bounces off the rim even if it is directly above it and is supposed to go through it. How would I allow the basketball to fall directly through the hoop? Here is my code. Thanks.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
//This is the basketball rim png that I put in my scene
        let rim = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "resized Basketball hoop.png")
        rim.position = CGPoint(x: 512, y: 384)
        rim.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: rim.texture!, size: rim.texture!.size())
        rim.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        addChild(rim)
        
        
        }
    
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
//This is when I touch the screen and a basketball falls from where I touched
        if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let basketball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basketball png.png")
        basketball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: basketball.size.width / 16)
        basketball.size.width = basketball.size.width / 8
        basketball.size.height = basketball.size.height / 8
        basketball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.4
        basketball.position = location
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        addChild(basketball)
            
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use two or more nodes to make a basketball rim.

Comment: Remove physicsbody from `rim`. Create 2 new sprites (1 for the left edge of the hoop, 1 for the right edge of the hoop), add a physicsbody to each of them, then change the z position so they appear behind the `rim` spritenode.